# iOS 7 / iPhone 4S Headphone Jack Doesn't Work

Tags: ios, error, headphones

My iPhone 4S that has iOS 7, the headphone jack won't work. In iOS 6 it did usually work but the sound was very low. After updating to iOS 7 the jack won't work at all. Can someone please help me out?

I use the original Apple iPhone Headphones I once bought from a Apple Store. I tested it on my iPhone 4 using iOS 6 and when i looked at the Headphone Jack it looked kinda damaged / had a crack! I listened to a quick song and the volume was very low!

[Headphones Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Zbt.jpg)

Comment: Can you try a known good pair of ear- or head-phones to see if it is the device or the phones?

Comment: I bought some new apple headphones and it still doesn't work. Wasted money :l

Comment: the simplest way to stop wasting money is to stop buying apple tech. :)